# Issue with Changing ListView items dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am basically trying to set an image to an ImageView which is an item in a ListView. The listview contains items that has ImageViews in them. I am trying to change the Imageview of the **first** item in that list.

```
crop_doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Bitmap croppedImage = CropImageView.getCroppedImage();

                //Instance of the adapter
                ProfileAdapter adapter =
                        new ProfileAdapter(EyewerProfile.this,
                                listData) {

                            @Override
                            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                                //The ImageView I need
                                ImageView userpic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userpic);

                                userpic.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);

                                return view;
                            }
                        };
            }
        });
```

This doesn't do anything and the imageview of the item doesn't change and it doesn't crash either. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
ImageView userpic = (ImageView) yourListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
userpic.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);
```

`position` should be 0 in your case.